# Javascript code in Asp.Net MVC project doesn't create array

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to run a code with Ajax that is supposed to generate a chart when clicking a button. When my page is loaded and I press the Button - that as the following code:

```
<div>

    <input id="btnAjax" name="btnAjax" type="button" value="Get Chart" />
    <div id="chart"> </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $('#btnAjax').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/BHome/Chart',
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html'

            })
            .success(function (result) {
                $('#chart').html(result);
            })
            .error(function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

The action that I call is this:

```
public ActionResult Chart()
        {
            var elements = db.Requests.GroupBy(user => user.submitUser)
                           .Select(slt => new { UsersCount = slt.Key, CountReq = slt.Count() });
            List<string> labels = new List<string>();
            List<int> values = new List<int>();

            foreach (var elem in elements)
            {
                labels.Add(elem.UsersCount);
                values.Add(elem.CountReq);
            }
            //ViewData["usersCounter"] = elements;
            StatisticsModel model = new StatisticsModel();
            model.Labels = labels.ToArray();
            model.Values = values.ToArray();

            return PartialView("_Chart", model);
        }
```

That calls this partial view:

```
<div style="width:30%">
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var myLabels = {}; 
@foreach (var label in Model.Labels)
{
    @:myLabels.push("@label");
        }

var myValues = {};
@foreach (var value in Model.Values)
{
    @:myValues.push("@value");
}

var lineChartData = {
    labels: myLabels,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: myValues
        }
    ]

}

window.onload = function () {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true
    });
}
```

The problem is that in this Script on PartialView, the only code that is getting run is the 2 foreach.

But if I do all this without the Ajax call, the runs good, and not only the 2 foreach.

Someone knows what's the problem?